# How can I export my LinkedIn messages?

Tags: linkedin, export

I wonder how to export the messages I have received and sent on LinkedIn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per LinkedIn's documentation:

> #### [LinkedIn > Download your account data](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/a1339364)
>
> 1. Click the  **Me** icon at the top of your LinkedIn homepage.
> 2. **Select Settings & Privacy** from the dropdown.
> 3. Click the **Data Privacy** on the left rail.
> 4. Under the **How LinkedIn uses your data** section, click **Get a copy of your data.**
> 5. Select the data that you’re looking for and **Request archive**.